# unsaved association in view is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller, I build a has_one association between junk and leads (but lead is an unsaved association):

```
@junkdata.each do |junk|
  lead = junk.build_lead
  junk.attributes.each_pair do |name,value|
    lead.send("#{name}=",value) if lead.respond_to? name
  end
end
```

In my view, I have two tabs. One displays information about junk. And the other is a form of a new lead object with data populated from junk's data. Problem is in my junkdata index.html.erb file, when I try to access the association it is nil:

```
<%= form_for junk.lead do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :reference_num %>
<% end %>
```

in other words, junk.lead is nil even though it wasn't in my controller. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: what is `junk` in your view? More code around what you have showed, will help. For example, is that controller code in your index action?

Comment: So you're trying to populate your `lead` object on the fly and then have it pre-populated in a form? Can you give us any more context?

Comment: @RichPeck yes exactly but its not a nested form, otherwise I could use fields_for. This is an independent form for lead.